# Using File_Type as a record component?

Tags: ada

I'm trying to write a lexer in Ada and have run into an issue.

```ada
procedure main is
    ...

    type lexer is tagged record
        input : ada.text_io.file_type;
        index : integer;
    end record;
    ...

    my_lexer : lexer;
    input_file_name : bounded_string;
    input_file : ada.text_io.file_type;
    next_token : token;
 begin
    input_file_name := get_input_file;

    ada.text_io.open(
        file => input_file,
        mode => ada.text_io.in_file,
        name => to_string(input_file_name)
    );

    my_lexer := (input => input_file, index => 0);
    next_token := my_lexer.get_next_token;
    ada.text_io.put_line(to_string(next_token.text));
end main;
```

On the line `my_lexer := (input => input_file);` I get the following error:

```
main.adb:22:17: nonlimited tagged type cannot have limited components
```

I understand this to be an issue since `ada.text_io.in_file` is a limited type, but if I were to just remove this from the record, and instead pass it as an argument to `get_next_token`,

```ada
    ...
    type lexer is tagged record
        index : integer;
    end record;

    function get_next_token(this: lexer'class; input_file: ada.text_io.file_type) return token;
    ...
```

Then this would make the state of the lexer invalid if you were to switch the `input_file` between calls of `get_next_token` thus breaking it.

Is there a way in Ada to create something like this like you would in C?

```c
struct lexer {
    FILE *input;
    int index;
};
```

Comment: You could try to make the `lexer` type `tagged limited` instead of `tagged` (i.e. non-limited).

Comment: @DeeDee I've tried this, but run into `left hand of assignment must not be limited type` meaning I couldn't initialize `my_lexer` right?

Comment: @DeeDee I managed to fix it, by creating an access type of `ada.text_io.file_type` and making `input_file` an aliased `ada.text_io.file_type` so I could take a pointer of `input_file`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach, allowing the `lexer` type to be `tagged limited` is to create the limited object in-place, so that its components (specifically the limited `file_type` component) aren't created elsewhere (legal) and then assigned (copied, illegal). In this case, the `file` component of `lexer` is passed to the `Open` call, which updates it in place.

```Ada
procedure lex2 is

    type lexer is tagged limited record
        input : ada.text_io.file_type;
        index : integer;
    end record;
    
    input_file_name : unbounded_string;
    my_lexer : lexer;
    -- next_token : token;
 begin
    input_file_name := get_input_file;
    my_lexer.index  := 0;
    ada.text_io.open( file => my_lexer.input,
                      mode => ada.text_io.in_file,
                      name => to_string(input_file_name));

    -- next_token := my_lexer.get_next_token;
    -- ada.text_io.put_line(to_string(next_token.text));
end lex2;
```

Comment: I'm running into an issue in the `declare` block, `initialization not allowed for limited types`.

Comment: I guess the issue is that `ada.text_io.file_type` is a limited type and thus I can't initialize it?

Answer (score 3):

Usually when you run into problems like this there are two solutions

1. Define a new type that is an access to the `limited` type and use it in your record, or
2. Make your type `limited`.  This is maybe (in my opinion) the cleaner solution since you do not have to mess with allocation, release, and stuff. (Personally, I try to avoid access types as much as possible).  Of course, making it limited will prevent you to assign it, but maybe this is not a major problem in the case of a lexer.

Answer (score 2):

What I'd do is hide all these details and create an abstraction:

```
package Lexing is
   type Info is tagged limited private;

   function Is_Open (State : in Info) return Boolean;
   -- Description of subprogram here

   procedure Open (State : in out Info; Name : in String) with
      Pre  => not State_Is_Open,
      Post => State.Is_Open;
   -- Description of subprogram here

   procedure Close (State : in out Info) with
      Pre  => State.Is_Open,
      Post => not State.Is_Open;
   -- Description of subprogram here

   type Token_Info is tagged private;

   function Next (State : in out Info) return Token_Info with
      Pre => State.Is_Open;
   -- Description of subprogram here

   function Text (Token : in Token_Info) return String;
   -- Description of subprogram here

   ...
private -- Lexing
   ...
end Lexing;
```

Obviously the fun bits are left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but this is what I've come up with:

```ada
 procedure main is
    type file_access is access all ada.text_io.file_type;
    
    ...

    type lexer is tagged record
        input : file_access;
        index : integer;
    end record;

    ...

    my_lexer : lexer;
    input_file_name : bounded_string;
    input_file : aliased ada.text_io.file_type;
    next_token : token;
 begin
    input_file_name := get_input_file;

    ada.text_io.open(
        file => input_file,
        mode => ada.text_io.in_file,
        name => to_string(input_file_name)
    );

    my_lexer := (input => input_file'access, index => 0);
    next_token := my_lexer.get_next_token;
    ada.text_io.put_line(to_string(next_token.text));
 end main;
```

Seems a bit convoluted, but I believe it's a way to ensure an access of `input_file` lives for as long as the procedure.